# Why is this LINQ query returning null when a match exists?

Tags: sql, linq

I have the following LINQ query, in a server-side rest API, but it is not matching existing records:

```
var existing = (from p in context.GameAction
                where p.GameId == gameId 
                    && p.GameDate == gameDate
                    && p.GamePlayerId == playerId
                    && p.ActionTypeId == actionTypeId
                    && p.PrevBoardPosition == prevBoardposition
                    && (p.ActionTargetId == null || p.ActionTargetId == actionTargetId)
                select p).FirstOrDefault();
if (existing == null)
{
    // create new action record...
}
else
{
    // Update existing game action record...
}
```

In this instance, the passed values are:

```
int gameId = 34
DateTime gameDate = {03/05/2013 00:00:00}
int actionTypeId = 1
int? prevBoardposition = null
int? actionTargetId = 52
```

And a record exists with these values (but null is returned by the query):

```
GameActionId    ActionTypeId    GameId  GameDate    GamePlayerId    ActionTargetId  PrevBoardPosition   MoveCount
2125            1               34      2013-05-03  220             NULL            NULL                13
```

The equivalent SQL generated should be something like this (and this does correctly return the above record):

```
SELECT [GameActionId]
      ,[ActionTypeId]
      ,[GameId]
      ,[GameDate]
      ,[GamePlayerId]
      ,[ActionTargetId]
      ,[PrevBoardPosition]
      ,[MoveCount]
  FROM [dbo].[GameAction]
  where [GameId]=34 and [GamePlayerId] = 220 
        and [GameDate] = '20130503' 
        and [ActionTypeId]=1 
        and ([PrevBoardPosition] is null or [ActionTargetId]=52)
```

Is this a problem with null matching nullable ints or is it something else I have overlooked?

### Update:

The generated SQL query sent to the server is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[GameActionId] AS [GameActionId], 
[Extent1].[ActionTypeId] AS [ActionTypeId], 
[Extent1].[GameId] AS [GameId], 
[Extent1].[GameDate] AS [GameDate], 
[Extent1].[GamePlayerId] AS [GamePlayerId], 
[Extent1].[ActionTargetId] AS [ActionTargetId], 
[Extent1].[PrevBoardPosition] AS [PrevBoardPosition], 
[Extent1].[MoveCount] AS [MoveCount]
FROM [dbo].[GameAction] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[GameId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[GameDate] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[GamePlayerId] = @p__linq__2) AND ([Extent1].[ActionTypeId] = @p__linq__3) AND ([Extent1].[PrevBoardPosition] = @p__linq__4) AND ([Extent1].[ActionTargetId] = @p__linq__5 OR [Extent1].[ActionTargetId] IS NULL)
```

Comment: Is it the same database (connectionstring) ?

Comment: Good point, but yes, there is only one database and one connection (I just checked the base class of the context and I am definitely using the same database). Adding generated SQL (extract via debugger) to question

Comment: Try removing the "and" clausules one by one. This way you will find in wich field you have the problem. I bet for the Date Field ;)

Comment: @Jonathan: Removing the date part of the query has no effect. As the dates are all created from DateTime.Date, there is no time part to interfere with the comparison.

Comment: @Jonathan: removing the prevBoardPosition check did work, so +1 for suggesting removing the clauses one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the null check on `PrevBoardPosition`. The generated SQL is using `PrevBoardPosition = NULL` which is never true. It needs to be `PrevBoardPosition IS NULL`.

Change it to the something like this:

```
 && prevBoardposition == null ? (p.PrevBoardPosition == null) : (p.PrevBoardPosition == prevBoardposition)
```

If that conditional operator is not supported by EF, you can change your query to only include the correct condition:

```
var query = from p in context.GameAction
            where p.GameId == gameId 
                && p.GameDate == gameDate
                && p.GamePlayerId == playerId
                && p.ActionTypeId == actionTypeId
                && (p.ActionTargetId == null || p.ActionTargetId == actionTargetId)
            select p;

if(prevBoardposition == null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.PrevBoardPosition == null);
else
    query = query.Where(x => x.PrevBoardPosition == prevBoardposition);

var existing = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: "which is always false" isn't quite right: it's unknown, not false. I'd put it as "which is never true".

Comment: @HiTechMagic: What you use now won't return the same results as your original query, because when `prevBoardposition` is `null` you now don't check that `p.PrevBoardPosition` is also `null`.

Comment: @HiTechMagic but that would return the record where `p.PrevBoardPosition == 1` if `prevBoardposition == null` is that what you want?

Comment: +1 The EF null problem is particularly illusive. good spotted!

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Bingo... You got it... Seems you can't treat nullable ints, with null values, as null. For consistency I went with (prevBoardposition == null) || p.PrevBoardPosition == prevBoardposition) as I only want to update the fields if they are null (or match if already changed).